# Harmonic functions on $\mathbb C-\{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Find all real-valued $C^2$ differentiable functions $h$ defined on $(0,\infty)$ such that $u(x,y)=h(x^2+y^2)$ is harmonic on $\mathbb C-\{0\}$.

This is one of my homework problem. As I understand I should find a function defined on $(0,∞)$ satisfy the conditions above. So far I only got $u(x,y)=\operatorname{In}(x^2+y^2)$ and maybe we can expand this to $u(x,y)=\operatorname{In}(x^2+y^2)^n$ every $n$ except for $0$. so can you correct me if I am wrong at any point and also help me complete the solution.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$\partial_x [h(x^2+y^2)]=2x\cdot h'(x^2+y^2),$$
hence 
$$\partial_{xx}[h(x^2+y^2)]=2 h'(x^2+y^2)+4x^2h''(x^2+y^2).$$
Similarly, we obtain 
$$\partial_{yy}[h(x^2+y^2)]=2 h'(x^2+y^2)+4y^2h''(x^2+y^2).$$
The Laplacian of $u$ at $(x,y)$ can be expressed as a function of $x^2+y^2$, hence we get a differential equation that $h$ needs to satisfy on $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: let t=x^2+y^2 then i get h(t)=-log t. just to make sure since i got log(x^2+y^2).